# how to extract data from trace files using awk and xxd

Tags: gawk, xargs

I am trying to extract data from a trace files and calculate the sum. For a single file, the following command works :

```
   cat avg.txt| gawk '{T+=$1} END {print T "\n"}'
```

But when I try using it with xargs command, as I have to do the same operation on multiple fils,I get a syntax error.

```
     ls *avg* |  xargs -i sh -c " cat {} | gawk '{T+=$1} END {print T "\n"}'"
```

gawk: {T+=} END {print T n}

gawk:     ^ syntax error

Can someone tell me what is the problem?

Comment: change your sh invocation to `sh -vxc "...` so you can see that is being procssed by the shell. Also, escape your awk `\$1`. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

xargs is adding a lot of complexity:

```
for file in *avg*; do
    gawk '{T+=$1} END {print FILENAME ": "T}' "$file"
done
```

The main problem with your code was the outer double quotes that allowed `$1` to be expanded as a shell variable .

Comment: But what if we wanted to run over thousands of files, where `xargs -P8` would help, but then the total would get spread over those multiple invocations of `awk`. Would piping to `bc` be the only option then ?

Answer (score 0):

With GNU Parallel you would do this:

```
sum() {
  gawk '{T+=$1} END {print FILENAME ": "T}' $1
}
export -f sum
parallel sum ::: *avg*
```